# How to create shaded css body

Tags: html, css

How can i create the box below? can someone please point me into the right direction? I don't have a lot of css experience.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking can be done with [`border-radius:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius) and [`box-shadow:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow) CSS properties.

Also, don't apply these directly on the `<body>` but have a general wrapper `<div>` or `<section>` to receive these properties.

Answer (score 2):

```
#box{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #333333;
    -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #333333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #333333;
    -o-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #333333;
    -ms-box-shadow:3px 3px 5px #333333;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -o-border-radius:4px;
    -ms-border-radius:4px;
}
```

I've added the `webkits` that you will require for the `box-shadow` to work on all browser platforms.

Comment: `border-radius` doesn't need vendor prefixes anymore. I believe `box-shadow` doesn't need them either.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha for what browsers? Safari I believe doesn't but Chrome and IE 9-10 Do I think?

Comment: I think both has their support just fine for all newest versions of the browsers.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha ohh ok. But I suppose things like `linear-gradients`, `rotations` and other fairly new properties still need the relative extension?

Comment: Yes. It's just that border-radius and box-shadow have been sufficiently implemented.

Comment: `border-radius` does not need prefixes for any browser anymore. `box-shadow` needs a `-webkit-` prefix only if you need to support Blackberry Browser or older Android. Gradients, transitions, animations only require a `-webkit-` prefix as current versions of Firefox, IE or Opera support them unprefixed. It's almost the same for transforms, except you'll also need to add a `-ms-` prefix in order to support IE9 (IE 10 supports unprefixed transforms)

Comment: Furthermore, `-o-border-radius`, `-ms-border-radius`, `-o-box-shadow`, `-ms-box-shadow` **never existed**! IE and Opera have supported them unprefixed since versions 9 and 10.5 respectively. And did not support them at all before that. And another thing: you should **always put the unprefixed property last**.

Comment: ahhh ok :) Thanks @Ana. Makes sense that `-ms-border-radius` and `box-shadow` never existed! As they never did. lol

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of CSS3. Use [border-radius](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp) and [box-shadow](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-shadow) properties.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this site: [CSS3 Generator](http://css3generator.com/)